# How to call a wp_list_categories to page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I used this code to my category.php and I want it to convert for my page template, this code is fully functional and working on category.php.

```html
<?php
if (in_category('interior')) {
 $cat = get_query_var('cat');
 $this_category = get_category($cat);
 $this_category = wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&hierarchical=false&order=ASC&orderby=title&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
if($this_category !='<li>No categories</li>') {
 echo '<ul class="ul-menu">'.$this_category.'</ul>'; 
}
}
?>
```

[Image Attached Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LfSX.jpg)

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Does it error or give the wrong value? can you add more information to this question?

Comment: @RAB I just want to it converts the code for a page template because this code is used for the category.php. No error

Comment: Do You want to access your category within a page?

Comment: Yeah @HarshKhare the category is interior

Comment: You want to show post or somthing else.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code into your page template.

```
$args = array (
'cat' => array(2,6,9,13),//use category id
'posts_per_page' => -1, //showposts is deprecated
'orderby' => 'date' //You can specify more filters to get the data 
 );

$cat_posts = new WP_query($args);
if ($cat_posts->have_posts()) : while ($cat_posts->have_posts()) : $cat_posts->the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
endwhile; endif;
```

I think its work for you. check and let me know

Comment: Hello, @Harsh Khare, you forgot to show the categories with its children, what I showed was a category filter. what i need is to show the categories with child and once click it loop posts will changed

Comment: Yeah actually it's working, what I need now is to show the category filter as my code posted.

Comment: I attached the image for you to easily understand it. I posted my code of my category filter to converted it for my page template because it was originally used for category.php

Comment: So you want to set children filter

Comment: Yes sir then i will make it used for my ajax